# How to launch Google Tv's Live Tv app without channel uri?

Tags: android-intent, uri, google-tv

I'm looking for a way to launch the live tv app of a google tv by intent without giving any channel uri.

I tried this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("tv://");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This code launch Live Tv app on a black screen and I can't change channels.

I tried fake uri too, but this trick only returns me this toast : 
"Could not tune to the requested stream"

When I launch the Live Tv app manually, in a conventional way, I can see the channels and navigate through them by pressing the CH+ and CH- buttons.

I can't use uri because the channel listing is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the anwser ! Follow this link for more informations : [Anymote to invoke keyevents on Google TV itsself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289518/anymote-to-invoke-keyevents-on-google-tv-itsself)

You can launch the live tv without channel uri by intent :

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tv://passthrough"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to tap into the Channel Listing api and manage the channel details yourself. Have a look at the Channel Listing APIs - https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_provider

Comment: Thank you Krispy. May be I don't understand your answer but I already try to query the provider and the table seems to be empty, that's my problem. I think that the cable box I use doesn't allow my buddy box (SONY NSZ-GS7) to fill in the table. That's why I try to launch the live tv app without information.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the data comes over the network not from the cable box itself. Did you configure you GTV with ZIP and Cable provider info when you set it up?

Comment: I configured my cable provider and my cable box model but my buddy box didn't ask for my ZIP code. May be it's because I'm in France and not in the US.

I agree with you, I think the data comes over the network. May be my Cable provider doesn't provide them, that's why my GTV doesn't found any information.

Comment: Ah yes if you are in France there will be issues as the TMS and EPG data has different licensing conditions. At this time GTV does not have TMS/EPG in France. You could however try to rig something up with an online service that does provide the TMS/EPG info - I know there are some sites you may be able to get the data from (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030422/anyone-know-of-a-open-free-universal-epg-xmltv-service)

Answer (score 0):

Once you know the channel number from your own channel data source, you should send the individual digits to the TV over Anymote (with a delay between each digit) to simulate a user typing in that channel number. This works consistently with various Google TV devices and in various countries.

Do not try and manipulate the TV Uri to make the TV change to a channel. The TV Uri format is not standardized and is different for different Google TV device manufacturers. Here are just a few examples:

```
tv://channel/VODDM?deviceId=irb_0&channelNumber=250
tv://channel?deviceId=irb_0&channelNumber=250
tv://channel/EHD?deviceId=Time%20Warner%20Cable
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now, I know how to launch the live tv app, I will try your advice in order to change the channels.